# Fix Imgur desktop vertical sizing

Tags: css, imgur, userscripts, browser-addons

It appears the Imgur site has been designed for mobile, with no consideration to
desktop users. Take this page (screenshot at the end):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmtSd.jpg

The video is vertical, and even with the window maximized you cannot see the
whole video, because they make no attempt to size it per the window size. I do
not see a setting to change this style:

[http://imgur.com/account/settings](https://imgur.com/account/settings)

Can this design be changed with a UserStyle, UserScript or Add-on?

> [image: crop]

Answer (score 2):

Note that you can right-click on the video itself, and then select *Full Screen* from the context menu.  This will show the whole video and works on most browsers, and many websites.

But a userstyle can be more convenient.  Here's one for [the Stylish extension](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stylish/info):

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);

@-moz-document domain("imgur.com") {
    .post-image img, .post-image object, .post-image video {
        max-height: 90vh !important;
    }
}
```

After you have installed Stylish, you can **install that style from [its userstyles.org page](https://userstyles.org/styles/149324/imgur-keep-videos-and-pics-within-the-screen-size).**

Comment: note Stylish is not compatible with FF57; I have switched to xStyle http://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/xstyle

Comment: Good to know.  Alas, FF57 looks to be breaking most of what I like about Firefox and turning it into a third-rate Chrome clone.

Comment: Yeah, tell me about it http://superuser.com/q/948192